# Comparing the characters of strings in an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have difficulty to write a function `f()` which receives an array `A` of strings and an integer `k`. Assume that array `A` is longer than `k`. The function returns `true` if and only if each string in `A` with `k` previous strings has at least one letter in common with each of those strings.

For example, if `A=[ "abcd", "efgh", "abe", "af", "bef" ]`, then `f(A,2)` returns `true` because:

- `"abe"` has at least one letter in common with both `"abcd"` and `"efgh"`;
- `"af"` has at least one bed in common with both `"efgh"` and `"abe"`;
- `"bef"` has at least one letter in common with both `"abe"` and `"af"`.

Here’s the code I tried to write:

```
bool f(char A[][5], int k)
{
    while(k<5)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<5; y++)
            {
                if( A[k][j]==A[k-1][y] && A[k][j]==A[k-2][y] )
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    char A[5][5]={"abcd", "efgh", "abe", "af", "bef"};
    
    cout << f(A,2);

    return 0;
}
```

Is that correct?

I have difficulty comparing the characters of the string in the array one by one.

Comment: "Is that correct? " what happened when you compiled and executed it ? Did you get expected results?

Comment: The output is "1" as I expected, but I wanted to know if the two nested for loops allow me to correctly compare all the characters of the strings in question.

Comment: Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted. Repeated low-quality questions may result in a temporary ban from asking new questions.

Comment: Why would you strive for `char[][]` instead of `string[]`?

Comment: @Giuseppe This sounds a lot like a homework assignment. If so, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/)

Answer (score 0):

No, your function is complete nonsense. You are supposed to count the number of words that match, but your function simply returns true if it finds two any words that happen to share a letter.

Let us start with a suitable data structure and proper naming for your variables:

```
bool f(const std::vector<std::string>& words, int k) {
  for (int word_idx = k; word_idx < words.size(); word_idx++) {
    auto& word = words[word_idx];
    int count = 0;

    // How many previous words do we share a letter with?
    for (int previous_word_idx = 0; previous_word_idx < k; previous_word_idx++) {
      auto& word2 = words[previous_word_idx];
      if (has_letter_in_common(word, word2)) count++;
    }

    if (count < k)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Writing `has_letter_in_common` is left for you to do.